# Apache mod_rewrite with multiple web apps

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite, cherrypy

I have 2 separate cherrypy web apps I have written and need to put them both behind Apache with mod_rewrite or something similar.  Need them to be accessed at http://domain.com/WebApp1 and http://domain.com/WebApp2.  I figured out how to do a single virtual host so far, but it is only accessible at http://domain.com/.  What would the correct configuration for Apache to get it to do this be?  Should I be using something other than mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the usage of mod_rewrite if the two application are made with cherrypy.

Mount each application in the cherrypy tree like this:

```
import cherrypy

from webapp1 import WebApp1
from webapp2 import WebApp2

cherrypy.tree.mount(WebApp1, '/WebApp1')
cherrypy.tree.mount(WebApp2, '/WebApp2')
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

For example:

```
 import cherrypy

 class AppOne(object):
     def index(self):
         return 'Hi from app one!'
     index.exposed = True

 class AppTwo(object):
     def index(self):
         return 'Hi from app two!'
     index.exposed = True

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     cherrypy.tree.mount(AppOne(), '/app1')
     cherrypy.tree.mount(AppTwo(), '/app2')
     cherrypy.engine.start()
     cherrypy.engine.block()
```

or:

```
 import cherrypy

 class AppOne(object):
     def index(self):
         return 'Hi from app one!'
     index.exposed = True

 class AppTwo(object):
     def index(self):
         return 'Hi from app two!'
     index.exposed = True

 class Root(object):
     app1 = AppOne()
     app2 = AppTwo()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     cherrypy.tree.mount(Root())
     cherrypy.engine.start()
     cherrypy.engine.block()
     # cherrypy.quickstart(Root()) # is the same
```

Another alternative is to use [mod_proxy](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModProxy).

Comment: Thank you sir!  This is the perfect answer to my problem.  I never even thought of doing it any of these ways.